# React + CSS Grid + MongoDB?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mongodb, gridview

Im creating a webpage in which users can post stuff to a "bulletin board". These posts are gonna be styled as boxes, and I want to add them to a grid layout. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
//import Gallery from "./components/gallery.component"
function App() {
  state = {
    posts = []; 
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPosts();
  };
  getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('(server)')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({ posts: data });
      })
  }
  displayBlogPost = (posts) => {
    if (!posts.length) return null;
    return posts.map((post, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="post__display">
        <h3>"name " + this.state.name </h3>
      </div>
    ));
  };
  render() {
      return (
            <div className="App">
        <header className="container">
          Logo
        </header>
            </div>
        <div className="gallery"> 
        {this.displayBlogPost(this.state.posts)} </div> 
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Im a little unsure of how to work on the grid. Ive been looking into the CSS Grid documentation and I was wondering if it would be enough to keep my code as is and create a css file with an id #gallery that sets the attributes of the grid (display, grid-gap, repeat, etc). Would this be enough, or will I have to change my displayBlogPost function. I'm worried that the approach will consider gallery just containing one element and therefore there wont even be a grid.

Would appreciate some clarification and suggestions, I tried to find examples online, but none seemed to use react, mongodb, and css grid.

Its also hard because Im a newbie to React and MongoDB and JavaScript in general, but this project is for a hackathon and Im on a time crunch

Answer (score 0):

Even though the post contains only one element the HTML DOM would show the grid in itself.
Yes, you can create a separate CSS file and include the req. CSS there.
Also, 

#### "name " + this.state.name

 you have not defined the state "name", how are you expecting for a display of value there?